Adding ubuntu server to active directory computers
Hi I'm trying to add my ubuntu server to my active directory computers list. When I try i'm greeted by this error:
error: krb5_get_default_realm failed


my conf file:
[libdefaults]
default = LOPES.COM
rdns = no
dns_lookup_realm = true
dns_lookup_kdc = true

[realms]
LOPES.COM = {
kdc = win-lopesmanufa.lopes.com:88
admin_server = win-lopesmanufa.lopes.com:749
default_domain = lopes.com
}

[domain_realm]
.lopes.com = LOPES.COM
lopes.com = LOPES.COM


The relation default does not seem to be defined in the section [libdefaults].
It would be better to use default_realm.

default = LOPES.COM
default_realm = LOPES.COM

HTH.
ref: MIT Kerberos Documentation
https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/admin/conf_files/krb5_conf.html#libdefaults

default_realm
Identifies the default Kerberos realm for the client.
Set its value to your Kerberos realm. If this value is not set, then a
realm must be specified with every Kerberos principal when invoking
programs such as kinit.

